# Conditional rendering of components in React (weather API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whenever I enter a wrong place or a blank value in the input, my screen goes blank and shows a no data found error

```
react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')
```

```
import React from "react";
const Weather = () => {
    const [city, setCity] = React.useState(null);
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("");
    const [place, setPlace] = React.useState("New York");
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const api = async () => {
            const Url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${place}&units=metric&appid=f61848ab5fa06141797d0d033e36ad85`;
            const response = await fetch(Url);
            const data = await response.json();
            setCity(data);
        };
        api();
    }, [place]);
    function handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setPlace(search)
        setSearch("")
    }
    function handlePress(event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            console.log("press")
            setPlace(search);
            setSearch("")
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handlePress}>
                <input type="search" value={search} onChange={(e) => { setSearch(e.target.value) }} />
                <button onClick={handleClick}>search</button>
            </form>
        

            {city ? (<p>No Data Found</p>) 

                : (<div>
                    {console.log("hello")}
                    <h1>Weather {city.main.temp}*c </h1>
                    <p> Place {city.name}</p>
                    <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${city.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`} alt="error" />
                </div>)}

        </div>
    )
}
export default Weather;
```

Comment: `city` doesn't have property named `main`

Comment: if i named with main property then I am not be able to access other elements like place or img

Answer (score 0):

check your `city` object if it has `main` property. Maybe replace it with `city.main?.temp` which will check if `.main` exist before trying to access it

---

also your condition `city` ? ... will not work if city is an empty object like {} because {} returns true. Make sure you know what you are checking here.

If you want to understand this topic better read couple articles on MDN about how objects represented in JS and how to build conditions. Will be helpful in the future.